# Ektron Dll for Ektron.Dxh.Common

Tags: ektron

Which all Dlls are required for using the namespace  Ektron.DxH.Common in Ektron.When I used Ektron.DxH.Common it showed an error saying

"The type or namespace name 'Common' does not exist in the namespace 'Ektron.DxH' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Any one please reply

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need the ContextBus DLLs. Namely:

```
ContextBus.Common
ContextBus.Logger
```